# Method 'Initialize' in type 'Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.GeneratorPlugin' does not have an implementation

Tags: specflow

When I install Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit I am getting floowing error.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1029  #error: 'Generation error: Method 'Initialize' in type 'Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.GeneratorPlugin' from assembly 'Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.SpecFlowPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.'    BDDSfecFlowSelenium c:\users\techjini\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BDDSfecFlowSelenium\BDDSfecFlowSelenium\features\GoogleSearch.feature.cs    1   Active

Comment: do you have a reference to BaseClass.contrib library?

Comment: Which version of SpecFlow are you using?